# Docusaurus + MDX + IntelliJ formatting

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, mdx, docusaurus

I would like to edit my Docs using IntelliJ but sadly the MDX files are not working well together with IntelliJ / WebStorm. There currently is an MDX Plugin that adds basic support but it breaks formatting.

Not only that the formatting is not working properly (like wrapping the lines) but also it keeps adding an empty line above the following import every time I run the format action:

```
---
title: My Page
---

import Image from '@theme/IdealImage'
```

This means that when applying a reformat before commit, all files are changed because they get a new line added on every commit.

Now I think that I am not the only one that wants to use JetBrains' editors for editing their Docusaurus project so I am here to ask what you are doing when it comes to formatting your MDX files.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you talking about this plugin (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14944-mdx) ? If so -- https://github.com/valentinnodan/mdx-intellij-plugin/issues/27 -- try making some noise there to attract some attention to the issue -- I do not think it will help TBH (very little to no activity in the tickets for a long while now), but worth trying nevertheless.